# Creating and Using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to the concept of arrays in java, and as part of an assignment, I am required to create a 10 row by 3 column integer array and populate it with a for loop. I have the following.

```
  public class arrays{

  int arr[][][] = new int [10][10][10];

    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;++j)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

am I on the right track?

Comment: If your idea of array dimension syntax was actually used by Java, how do you imagine creating a 10 row by 3,000,000 column array would look like?

Comment: I dunno. hence am here seeking help.,

Comment: @user3263215 I hope it is now clear for you, see the [trails tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually declaring a 3-dimensional array.
You should instead be declaring `int[][] arr = new int[10][3];`.
You can then assign values as follows: `arr[i][j] = 42;`

Note also that when instantiated, the initial values in the array are 0.

Comment: Ah i see. I am trying to populate the first and second column with some numbers. Is the for loop i've got suitable for this?

Comment: @user3263215 looks fine for iterating through.

Answer (score 0):

The way of creating array in java is simple and I see you know that but for your problem applicable array might be different. Try that one
`int arr[][] = new int [10][3];`

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){
      arr[i][j] = your_integer_value;
   }

}
```